# How to configure openssl to work with file_get_contents

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, recaptcha

We run an apache2 server and want to use google recaptcha due to high volume of bots on our newsletter.

Therefore I implemented some lines of developers php-code which in general should work ... but not on my server.
I investigated further and found that the function file_get_contents() ends with an SSL error.

```
file_get_contents(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL, false, $context)
```

Below you can find an extract from the servers log file.

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/html/app/lib/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php on line 68
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/html/app/lib/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php on line 68
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/html/app/lib/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php on line 68
```

This brought me to the conclusion that Openssl is misconfigured.
So I:

- reinstalled ca-certificates with apt-get purge ca-certificate
- Also downloaded the cacert.pem and linked it in the php.ini
- checked if curl works properly, but it doesnt (every call of curl ends with `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`
- checked openssl.cnf which looks ok to me.

Any ideas how to solve this would be great.

Comment: Can you make a file on your server with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and then show what values it has for `openssl.cafile` and `openssl.capath`? PHP still may not be configured correctly to see the certs in the right location. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/722646) shows the proper path for various Linux distributions. You'll want to make sure that `openssl.cafile` and `curl.cainfo` are both set to the appropriate .pem file.

Comment: The value for `openssl.cafile` is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`  for `openssl.capath` it is `/etc/ssl/certs`. I checked the crt file. It is in the folder, formatting looks ok and was updated recently. When I go back to my inital problem of retrieving object from google the error message changed: `failed loading cafile stream: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' in /var/www/html/app/lib/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php on line 68`

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem:
First I changed the filepath according to the comment by drew010.
Then I fixed issues on my server with file permissions of /etc/ssl/certs according to this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/636979

Now file_get_contents does not invoke any errors and recaptcha runs smoothly.